# SQL Query Second sum column squaring results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, sum

If I run 2 queries separately I get results like this..

```
 select A.ACTNUMST, sum(B.EXTDCOST) as [IV Total]
 from GL00105 A
 INNER JOIN SEE30303 B on A.ACTINDX = B.IVIVINDX
 group by A.ACTNUMST

 Results -
 Account No      IV Total
 2101-00-137     2033.60
 4101-00-137     83765.86
 6101-00-137     301984.23
```

Second Query

```
 select A.ACTNUMST as [Account No], SUM(C.PERDBLNC) as [GL Total]
 from GL00105 A
 LEFT JOIN GL10110 C on A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
 group by A.ACTNUMST

 Results -
 Account No      GL Total
 2101-00-137     2033.60
 4101-00-137     83765.86
 6101-00-137     302656.23
```

I want to be able to join both results together to compare but I believe it is repeating the sum for each line in the GL total and then summing it again, it comes out with large numbers like -

```
 select A.ACTNUMST as [Account No], sum(B.EXTDCOST) as [IV Total], SUM(C.PERDBLNC) as [GL Total]
 from GL00105 A
 INNER JOIN SEE30303 B on A.ACTINDX = B.IVIVINDX
 LEFT JOIN GL10110 C on A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
 group by A.ACTNUMST

 Results -
 Account No      IV Total        GL Total
 2101-00-137     2033.60         14235.20
 4101-00-137     83765.86        116350696.20
 6101-00-137     301984.23       1612897825.84
```

When it should be

```
 Results -
 Account No      IV Total        GL Total
 2101-00-137     2033.60         2033.60
 4101-00-137     83765.86        83765.86
 6101-00-137     301984.23       302656.23
```

Please advise how to use the sum function to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Please check and comment if this is not what is expected.

Also please rectify any syntax errors.

```
SELECT T1.[Account No], T1.[IV Total], T2.[GL Total] FROM
(
    select A.ACTNUMST as [Account No], sum(B.EXTDCOST) as [IV Total]
    from GL00105 A
    INNER JOIN SEE30303 B on A.ACTINDX = B.IVIVINDX
    group by A.ACTNUMST
) T1
INNER JOIN
(
    select A.ACTNUMST as [Account No], SUM(C.PERDBLNC) as [GL Total]
    from GL00105 A
    LEFT JOIN GL10110 C on A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
    group by A.ACTNUMST
) T2
ON T1.[Account No] = T2.[Account No]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's great thanks. Solves my problem. I followed the same logic but tried to simplify it a bit and got the result I wanted.

select T3.ACTNUMST as [Account No], T1.[IV Total], T2.[GL Total] from 

(select IVIVINDX as [Index], SUM(EXTDCOST) as [IV Total]
from SEE30303
group by IVIVINDX)T1

INNER JOIN

(select ACTINDX as [Index], sum(PERDBLNC) as [GL Total]
from GL10110
group by ACTINDX) T2 on T1.[Index] = T2.[Index]

INNER JOIN GL00105 T3 on T1.[Index] = T3.[ACTINDX]

order by T3.ACTNUMST

Comment: Not sure how to enter the code part on a comment? New to this forum... The 5 spaces doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nice to know that. Please upvote and/or mark as accepted if the answer was useful to you. :)

Comment: You can use a backtick i.e. ` to add code block in a comment which is below the Esc button in most keyboards. So your code will look something like this  `This is a code`. Need not do it in this question but you can do it in your subsequent posts. Check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments

Comment: 'select T3.ACTNUMST as [Account No], T1.[IV Total], T2.[GL Total] from (select IVIVINDX as [Index], SUM(EXTDCOST) as [IV Total] from SEE30303 group by IVIVINDX)T1 INNER JOIN (select ACTINDX as [Index], sum(PERDBLNC) as [GL Total] from GL10110 group by ACTINDX) T2 on T1.[Index] = T2.[Index] INNER JOIN GL00105 T3 on T1.[Index] = T3.[ACTINDX] order by T3.ACTNUMST'

Comment: Hah Sorry about the notifications you will be receiving.. It's the end of a long day. Finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with the multiple cte  also

```
 with IVTotal as
 (
     select A.ACTNUMST, sum(B.EXTDCOST) as [IV Total]
     from   GL00105 A
     INNER  JOIN SEE30303 B 
     on     A.ACTINDX = B.IVIVINDX
     group  by A.ACTNUMST
 ),  
 GLTotal as 
 (
     select A.ACTNUMST as [Account No], SUM(C.PERDBLNC) as [GL Total]
     from   GL00105 A
     LEFT   JOIN GL10110 C 
     on     A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX
     group  by A.ACTNUMST
 )
 select a.*,b.[GL Total] 
 from   IVTotal a ,GLTotal b
 where  a.ACTNUMST =  b.aCTNUMST
```